# Why are some file not be able to merge history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I merged branch to trunk, using tortoise SVN. Some file can merge history, others failed to merge. I merged two different trees(branch and trunk), all file is same content, there is no different. However some file seemed to be failed merge history. I have no idea. What kind of causes can you think of?

```
Merging process:
Checkout repository to local PC.
Press right click and select SVN merge.
Select merge two difference tree
Enter path below
From(start URL revision of range to merge)
  C:xxx/repo/trunk (head revision)
To:(end URL revision of range to merge)
  C:xxx/repo/branch (head revision)
Working copy
  C:xxx/repo/trunk
Merge depth
  Working copy
Get start merging.
```

There are no error messages.

Comment: I’m afraid that the case is unclear. It would be helpful to see an example with commands you run and error messages (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to choose the option [Merge a range of revisions](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html#tsvn-dug-merge-range) since it looks like you just need to merge changes from one branch into trunk.

It's still unclear what you mean by "failed to merge". I've just tested the 'Merge two different trees' option and it works.